# Jenkins CF plugin using API key

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to have the [CF plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cloud+Foundry+Plugin) use an API key instead of username and password for logging in and pushing an application to IBM Cloud Platform?

Here is a very bare bones Jenkinsfile I am using to test out the plugin

```
node('workers') {
  echo "Running ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"

//   properties(
//     [
//         pipelineTriggers([cron('0 16 * * * ')]),
//     ]
//   )

  stage('checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('Build') {
      if (isTimer()) {
          echo "building by timer"
      }
      echo 'building'
  }
  stage('Test') {
    echo 'Testing..'
  }
  stage('Deploy') {
    pushToCloudFoundry(
        target: 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net',
        organization: 'WXS',
        cloudSpace: 'dev',
        credentialsId: 'cfplugin-henry-test'
    )
  }
}
```

The credentialsId `cfplugin-henry-test` is a secret text on Jenkins that has my API key. However, the Jenkins build gives back `ERROR: No credentials have been given.`

So does the plugin not have the capability of logging in with an API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script that downloads the IBM Cloud CLI and do the cf push you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Installing the IBM Cloud API v.0.6.6"

wget https://public.dhe.ibm.com/cloud/bluemix/cli/bluemix-cli/0.6.6/IBM_Cloud_CLI_0.6.6_amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvf IBM_Cloud_CLI_0.6.6_amd64.tar.gz
./Bluemix_CLI/install_bluemix_cli


# Ignore updates because they need confirmation from the user
bx config --check-version=false

bx api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
bx login
bx target -o wxs -s dev
bx cf push
```

Make sure you have a value for `BLUEMIX_API_KEY` that's what `bx login` will use.

I adapted the script from the [`bx-blue-green`](https://github.com/andresfvilla/bx-blue-green) npm module that I use in Travis.